# Format the output of Join Query

Tags: sql, oracle, output

I have a join query which gives below output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOC.STATE, ORD.* FROM 
( 
    SELECT COUNT (*) ORDERS, 
    ORDV.PERSON_ID PERSON_ID,
    PERSON.FIRST_NAME FN,
    PERSON.LAST_NAME LN,
    SOURCE 
    FROM MY_ORD_V ORDV, EIM_PERSON PERSON
    WHERE ORD_STATUS_ID NOT IN (A, C, D, F)
         AND PERSON.PERSON_ID = ORDV.PERSON_ID
         GROUP BY ORDV.PERSON_ID,
         SOURCE,
         PERSON.FIRST_NAME,
         PERSON.LAST_NAME
    ORDER BY 1 ASC
) ORD , MY_LOCATION_V LOC
    WHERE ORD.PERSON_ID = LOC.OBJ_ID ORDER BY LOC.STATE, ORD.FN, ORD.LN
```

Current output and Expected output:

[image: Current output and Expected output]

Comment: Edit your question so it has the current and expected output.  Don't make your question rely on external web sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Oracle 11g you now have the [LISTAGG analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030). This might be what you're looking for (demo SQL that I used for testing):

```
SELECT DISTINCT state, LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(orders)||src, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fn, ln) OVER (PARTITION BY state, fn, ln) as orders
     , fn
     , ln
FROM (
SELECT 'NY' as state, 2 as orders, 'GREG' as fn, 'BOOTINE' as ln, 'DBS' as src from dual
union all
SELECT 'NY' as state, 3 as orders, 'GREG' as fn, 'BOOTINE' as ln, 'PST' as src from dual
union all
SELECT 'MA' as state, 2 as orders, 'ANN' as fn, 'SILVEST' as ln, 'DBS' as src from dual
union all
SELECT 'MA' as state, 2 as orders, 'ANN' as fn, 'SILVEST' as ln, 'PST' as src from dual
)
```

Using your SQL it would go something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT state
     , LISTAGG(TO_CHAR(orders)||src, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY fn, ln) OVER (PARTITION BY state, fn, ln) as orders
     , fn
     , ln
FROM ( 
    SELECT COUNT (*) ORDERS, 
    ORDV.PERSON_ID PERSON_ID,
    PERSON.FIRST_NAME FN,
    PERSON.LAST_NAME LN,
    SOURCE 
    FROM MY_ORD_V ORDV, EIM_PERSON PERSON
    WHERE ORD_STATUS_ID NOT IN (A, C, D, F)
         AND PERSON.PERSON_ID = ORDV.PERSON_ID
         GROUP BY ORDV.PERSON_ID,
         SOURCE,
         PERSON.FIRST_NAME,
         PERSON.LAST_NAME
    ORDER BY 1 ASC
) ORD , MY_LOCATION_V LOC
    WHERE ORD.PERSON_ID = LOC.OBJ_ID 
  ORDER BY LOC.STATE, ORD.FN, ORD.LN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative version, just a pseudo query showing the idea. You can concatenate with `||` in oracle. Like this you will always have both sources, also when the count is 0. If source needs to be dynamic you could still do it like this by getting all the distinct sources in a subquery (and then use `group` and `listagg` as @Patrick Marchand says).

```
SELECT
  p.state,
  p.first_name,
  p.last_name,
  ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.person_id = p.person_id AND o.source = 'DBS'
  ) dbs_count,
  ( SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM orders o
    WHERE o.person_id = p.person_id AND o.source = 'PST'
  ) pst_count
FROM
  person p
ORDER BY
  p.state, p.first_name, p.last_name
```